# Get a view controller's class name as string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, introspection

If I have a `UIViewController` subclass, how can I get the class name as string? I've tried doing `[vc class]`, but this returns a `Class` object, not an `NSString`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print the type or class of a variable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> ## [NSStringFromClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass)
>
> Returns the name of a class as a string.
>
> ```
> NSString * NSStringFromClass (  
>     Class aClass  
> );
> ```

Comment: If ending up here from google and actually want the SWIFT 3 answer, use eg: `String(describing: MyViewController.self)` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878224/1736679

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like this

```
NSString *strClass = NSStringFromClass([viewController class]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the function:

```
const char * class_getName(Class cls)
```

as

```
class_getName ([vc class]);
```

Comment: how do I cast from char* to NSString?

Comment: you don't cast from char* to NSString. You have to create a string from bytes using a call like initWithBytes:length:encoding:. You'd probably use use the encoding NSASCIIStringEncoding. See the other poster's message about NSStringFromClass. That's much easier to use than the Objective C runtime function class_getName().

Comment: `class_getName()` is the runtime function that NSStringFromClass would use under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

you can do some thing like the following when you instantiate your object:

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"className1") alloc] init];
```

Comment: xonegirlz asked how to get an NSString from a class, and your answer gets an instance of a class from an NSString (i.e. you gave the reverse of the answer).