# How to create Dictionary that can hold anything in Key? or all the possible type it capable to hold

Tags: swift

I want to create a `Dictionary` that does not limit the key type (like `NSDictionary`)

So I tried

```
var dict = Dictionary<Any, Int>()
```

and

```
var dict = Dictionary<AnyObject, Int>()
```

resulting

```
error: type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
var dict = Dictionary<Any, Int>()
           ^
<REPL>:5:12: error: cannot convert the expression's type '<<error type>>' to type '$T1'
var dict = Dictionary<Any, Int>()
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

OK, I will use `Hashable`

```
var dict = Dictionary<Hashable, Int>()
```

but

```
error: type 'Hashable' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
var dict = Dictionary<Hashable, Int>()
           ^
Swift.Equatable:2:8: note: '==' requirement refers to 'Self' type
  func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
       ^
Swift.Hashable:1:10: note: type 'Hashable' does not conform to inherited protocol 'Equatable.Protocol'
protocol Hashable : Equatable
         ^
<REPL>:5:12: error: cannot convert the expression's type '<<error type>>' to type '$T1'
var dict = Dictionary<Hashable, Int>()
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So `Hashable` inherited from `Equatable` but it does not conform to `Equatable`??? I don't understand...

Anyway, keep trying

```
typealias KeyType = protocol<Hashable, Equatable> // KeyType is both Hashable and Equatable
var dict = Dictionary<KeyType, Int>() // now you happy?
```

with no luck

```
error: type 'KeyType' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
var dict = Dictionary<KeyType, Int>()
           ^
Swift.Equatable:2:8: note: '==' requirement refers to 'Self' type
  func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
       ^
Swift.Hashable:1:10: note: type 'KeyType' does not conform to inherited protocol 'Equatable.Protocol'
protocol Hashable : Equatable
         ^
<REPL>:6:12: error: cannot convert the expression's type '<<error type>>' to type '$T1'
var dict = Dictionary<KeyType, Int>()
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am so lost now, how can I make compiler happy with my code?

---

I want to use the dictionary like

```
var dict = Dictionary<Any, Int>()
dict[1] = 2
dict["key"] = 3
dict[SomeEnum.SomeValue] = 4
```

---

I know I can use `Dictionary<NSObject, Int>`, but it is not really what I want.

Comment: make a class that conforms to Hashable and Equatable?

Comment: @sjeohp how is that useful? it limit the key type to be that class only. and if you really mean make a new `protocol`, that also won't help. because I can't extents every other class to make them conform my protocol

Comment: well one way or another you have to convince Dictionary that your generic key type can be both hashed and compared for equality, since that's how a dictionary works

Comment: otherwise you could implement your own dictionary with your own hash/compare methods

Comment: @sjeohp have no idea about how generic may help. and I am fighting with the type checker, even with my own dictionary implementation, I still will have same problem. Because the type checker is going to do the same thing to me again on the new dictionary type.

Comment: Is there a reason `AnyObject` does not conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable`? Is there a known subtype of `AnyObject` that would not do well by this?

Comment: @CraigOtis what do you mean? `AnyObject` is `@class_protocol protocol AnyObject {}`, which by definition, does not conform to any protocol

Comment: Right, I know that it *doesn't*, I was just (philosophically) pondering what the world would be like if it *did*, like so: `@class_protocol protocol BetterAnyObject : NSObjectProtocol, Equatable, Hashable {}`

Comment: @CraigOtis thats basically `NSObject`

Comment: I think that might be the answer to your question then - if a `Dictionary` requires that its keys be both equatable and hashable, and `NSObject` is the most generic type that implements both, that's what you need to use as your key. (Even though I know you mention not wanting to use that, it seems the only option with what's currently available.)

Comment: @CraigOtis well, it is the fallback solution. which stop me put `struct` and `enum` into the dictionary.

Comment: Which makes sense. If the compiler can't guarantee that an `enum` will be able to provide a hash at runtime, and the `Dictionary` requires that of its keys, you can't use `enum` types as keys. As another commenter mentions, your best bet might be a custom subclass that supports enum/struct keys.

Comment: @CraigOtis I guess I can have wrapper class to hold enum and struct. but the compiler _can_ guarantee that because I can make `enum`(and `struct`) conform to `Hashable` and if the type system works as I expected, it should accept anything conform to `Hashable` (`class`, `struct` and `enum)`

Comment: I took the liberty of cross-posting / linking to this question on a separate post on the Apple Dev forums and this question is answered here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1045616 .

Comment: Use NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 72):

#### Swift 3 update

You can now use `AnyHashable` which is a type-erased hashable value, created exactly for scenarios like this:

`var dict = Dictionary<AnyHashable, Int>()`

Comment: This is the answer..!

Answer (score 17):

I believe that, as of Swift 1.2, you can use an ObjectIdentifier struct for this. It implements Hashable (and hence Equatable) as well as Comparable. You can use it to wrap any class instance. I'm guessing the implementation uses the wrapped object's underlying address for the hashValue, as well as within the == operator.

Comment: This is the correct answer to this question, not sure why it isn't marked/voted as such

Answer (score 11):

I took the liberty of cross-posting / linking to this question on a separate post on the Apple Dev forums and this question is [answered here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1045616).

### Edit

This answer from the above link works in 6.1 and greater:

```
struct AnyKey: Hashable {
    private let underlying: Any
    private let hashValueFunc: () -> Int
    private let equalityFunc: (Any) -> Bool

    init<T: Hashable>(_ key: T) {
        underlying = key
        // Capture the key's hashability and equatability using closures.
        // The Key shares the hash of the underlying value.
        hashValueFunc = { key.hashValue }

        // The Key is equal to a Key of the same underlying type,
        // whose underlying value is "==" to ours.
        equalityFunc = {
            if let other = $0 as? T {
                return key == other
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return hashValueFunc() }
}

func ==(x: AnyKey, y: AnyKey) -> Bool {
    return x.equalityFunc(y.underlying)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add AnyKey("string") at the call site. Something to be aware of if you're designing a public interface.

Comment: Those unfamiliar with the above "Type Erasure" technique will enjoy @rob-napier's talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCxkaTj7QJs

Answer (score 7):

Dictionary is `struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value>...`
Which means that Value could be anything you want, and Key could be any type you want, but Key must conform to `Hashable` protocol.

You can't create `Dictionary<Any, Int>()` or `Dictionary<AnyObject, Int>()`, because `Any` and `AnyObject` can't guarantee that such a Key conforms `Hashable`

You can't create `Dictionary<Hashable, Int>()`, because `Hashable` is not a type it is just protocol which is describing needed type.

> So Hashable inherited from Equatable but it does not conform to
>   Equatable??? I don't understand...

But you are wrong in terminology. Original error is

`type 'Hashable' does not conform to inherited protocol 'Equatable.Protocol'`
That means that Xcode assuming 'Hashable' as some type, but there is no such type. And Xcode treat it as some kind empty type, which obviously does not conform any protocol at all (in this case it does not conform to inherited protocol `Equatable`)

Something similar happens with `KeyType`.

> A type alias declaration introduces a named alias of an existing type into your program.

You see `existing type`. `protocol<Hashable, Equatable>` is not a type it is protocol so Xcode again tells you that `type 'KeyType' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`

You can use `Dictionary<NSObject, Int>` just, because `NSObject` conforms `Hashable` protocol.

Swift is strong typing language and you can't do some things like `creating Dictionary that can hold anything in Key`. Actually dictionary already supports any can hold anything in Key, which conforms `Hashable`. But since you should specify particular class you can't do this for native Swift classes, because there is no such master class in Swift like in Objective-C, which conforms air could conform (with a help of extensions) to `Hashable`

Of course you can use some wrapper like `chrisco` suggested. But I really can't imagine why you need it. It is great that you have strong typing in Swift so you don't need to worry about types casting as you did in Objective-C

Answer (score 2):

`Hashable` is just a protocol so you can't specify it directly as a type for the `Key` value. What you really need is a way of expressing "any type T, such that T implements `Hashable`. This is handled by type constraints in Swift:

```
func makeDict<T: Hashable>(arr: T[]) {
  let x = Dictionary<T, Int>()
}
```

This code compiles.

AFAIK, you can only use type constraints on generic functions and classes.

Comment: Is any reason I can't specify `Hashable` directly as a type for the Key? I can do it for value. and my aim it to create dictionary that key can be `Int` and `String` and anything conform to `Hashable`

Comment: This will work for any T that implements Hashable, which includes Int and String.

Comment: but it only works for Int _or_ String. I want Int _and_ String

Comment: That's a pretty unusual use case. Can you explain?

Comment: thats what `NSDictioanry` can do, the key type just need to conform `NSCopying` which can be `NSString` or `NSNumber`

Comment: Yes, but it's typically used with a key of a single type. What is the underlying reason for needing this data structure?

Comment: mainly because I want to know how to do it in swift. and it can be useful for library code to accept different custom defined key type

Comment: @Bill Who cares what the underlying reason is. The point is Bryan has found a pretty significant limitation in Swift that Obj-C doesn't have. I'm running into a similar problem myself with generics in Swift. Pretty much any other language could do this with Protocols or Interfaces. Swift's implementation is very poor here.

Comment: @chaiguy It's fairly common to ask a poster for context and a higher-level description of the problem. This strikes me as an unusual thing to do, so I asked for more information.

Comment: @Bill I apologize for my tone. Of course asking for clarification is fine; it just sounded like you were defending the limitation because you didn't consider his reason valid. Tbh I'm getting very frustrated with Swift's limitations, even though I obviously realize it's still prerelease.

Comment: I want this functionality to keep track or results from different objects without having to make the objects conform to Hashable, see below for my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but has helped me.

The general answer would be implement Hashable for all your types, however that can be hard for Protocols because Hashable extends Equatable and Equatable uses Self which imposes severe limitations on what a protocol can be used for.

Instead implement Printable and then do:

```
var dict = [String: Int]
dict[key.description] = 3
```

The implementation of description has to be something like:

```
var description : String {
    return "<TypeName>[\(<Field1>), \(<Field2>), ...]"
}
```

Not a perfect answer, but the best I have so far :(

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me figure out how to solve my particular problem, which I've posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the OP's question, but is somewhat related, and may hopefully be of use for some situations. Suppose that what you really want to do is this:

```
   public var classTypeToClassNumber = [Any.Type : Int]()
```

But Swift is telling you "Type 'Any.Type' does not conform to protocol Hashable".

Most of the above answers are about using object instances as a dictionary key, not using the type of the object. (Which is fair enough, that's what the OP was asking about.) It was the answer by Howard Lovatt that led me to a usable solution.

```
public class ClassNumberVsClassType {

   public var classTypeToClassNumber = [String : Int]()

   public init() {

      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassWithStringKey.self)] = 367622
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassBasedOnKeyedItemList3.self)] = 367629
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassBasedOnKeyedItemList2.self)] = 367626
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassWithGuidKey.self)] = 367623
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: SimpleStruct.self)] = 367619
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: TestData.self)] = 367627
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ETestEnum.self)] = 367617
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassBasedOnKeyedItemList0.self)] = 367624
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: ClassBasedOnKeyedItemList1.self)] = 367625
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: SimpleClass.self)] = 367620
      classTypeToClassNumber[String(describing: DerivedClass.self)] = 367621
   }

   public func findClassNumber(_ theType : Any.Type) -> Int {
      var s = String(describing: theType)
      if s.hasSuffix(".Type") {
         s = s.substring(to: s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -5))  // Remove ".Type"
      }
      let classNumber = _classTypeToClassNumber[s]
      return classNumber != nil ? classNumber! : -1
   }
}
```

EDIT:

If the classes involved are defined in different modules, and may have conflicting class names if you neglect the module name, then substitute "String(reflecting:" for "String(describing:", both when building up the dictionary and when doing the lookup.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the class name as a Hashable, e.g.:

```
var dict = [String: Int]
dict[object_getClassName("key")] = 3
```

See [How do I print the type or class of a variable in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift) for how you might get the class name.

Comment: Oops re-read question following the comment, it doesn't solve the question. It solves the question only if each object in the dict is a different type. This was my use case and therefore it solved my problem, however it is not the question asked - sorry.