# What does "Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" mean?

Tags: swift, generics, xcode6, swift-protocols

I am trying to create a Dictionary (actually a [HashSet](https://gist.github.com/devios1/d8914833912c1aae15e2)) keyed on a custom protocol in Swift, but it is giving me the error in the title:

> Protocol 'myProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

and I can't make heads nor tails of it.

```
protocol Observing: Hashable { }

var observers = HashSet<Observing>()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Dictionary that can hold anything in Key? or all the possible type it capable to hold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119624/how-to-create-dictionary-that-can-hold-anything-in-key-or-all-the-possible-type)

Comment: @jtbandes That's not a duplicate. I'm asking what the error message actually means. What is a "Self or associated type requirement"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of protocols as array types and function parameters in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888560/usage-of-protocols-as-array-types-and-function-parameters-in-swift)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Protocol `Observing` inherits from protocol `Hashable`, which in turn inherits from protocol `Equatable`. Protocol `Equatable` has the following requirement:

```
func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

And a protocol that contains `Self` somewhere inside it cannot be used anywhere except in a type constraint.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888560/usage-of-protocols-as-array-types-and-function-parameters-in-swift) is a similar question.

Comment: ...because the compiler has to ensure it's the *same* type on either side, but the protocol only ensures it meets the contract. I see. Still, it seems like `Equatable` ought not to necessarily imply `Equatable` since that's not strictly necessary to generate a hash code.

Comment: Oh no wait it does, because `Dictionary` needs to be able to know if a given object is indeed the correct key, because it's possible for two different objects to generate the same hash code. Hmm, that is a bit tricky. So the problem here is really with `Equatable`.

Comment: Look at 0:56 into the great presentation by Alexis Gallagher titled: Protocols with Associated Types and how they got that way (maybe)  https://youtu.be/XWoNjiSPqI8

Comment: Swift is truly one of the most poorly designed languages I have ever seen...

Answer (score 12):

To solve this you could use generics. Consider this example:

```
class GenericClass<T: Observing> {
   var observers = HashSet<T>()
}
```