# Swift: Function returning an Array of IntegerType

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to create a function that takes an `NSData` parameter, and, depending on what it reads from the `NSData` it returns an `Array<Int8>`, `Array<Int16>`, `Array<Int32>`, or `Array<Int64>`.

Basically, I need to return an array of `IntegerType`, with the specific subtype being determined at runtime.

I am stuck at the signature declaration of the function. (The inside would just be a simple switch, that would create the specific array type and return it).

The following very basic test does not compile

```
class Test {
    func test(data:NSData) -> Array<IntegerType> {
      return [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems to be currently not possible, not because of having to return an array of a protocol type, but because the IntegerType protocol uses `Self`. Here is an interesting related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The official Apple documentation itself asks you to use Int for any integer size https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_479

Comment: A consistent use of Int for integer values aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference

Comment: If you must, just return [Any] and do all the type checking after the data is returned

Comment: _"Basically, I need to return an array of IntegerType, with the specific subtype being determined at runtime."_  -- Not possible. Inferred types will be determined at compile time. Your basic approach should either be generic the whole way, or use `Int` as the common type (if possible).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I don't need the type to be inferred. I just need it to be Array<IntegerType>

Comment: In the generic `Array<T>`, `T` refers to the "placeholder type name". `T` must be replaced with a _type_ when a type, say `Array<Int>` will be instantiated. `IntegerType` is not a type, it's a protocol.

Comment: @Eduardo You are assuming a parallelism between generic function parameters and generic return values that doesn't exist. Consider this: how would you declare a variable to store the return value of your function? The type has to be known at compile time to allocate storage, but there's no way to know the actual type of the return value until runtime. At compile time you know only that it conforms to the IntegerType protocol.

Comment: @ToddAgulnick The actual type will be determined inside my function, from a finite number of types compatible with [IntegerType]. There is enough information inside the function to allocate storage for that and initialize the array. The compiler just needs to know that what I return is an array of some type that conforms to IntegerType. It may be that Swift does not allow this kind of polymorphism; other languages do.

Comment: @Eduardo Another view: Swift Arrays when declared must specify the type of objects that they contain. `IntegerType`, despite its name, is not a type but a protocol. So there's no way (syntactically) to declare a variable to hold the return value of your proposed function.

Comment: @ToddAgulnick: according to the Swift language guide (Protocol as Types section): "any protocol you create will become a fully-fledged type for use in your code ... you can use a protocol in many places where other types are allowed, including as a return type in a function, ... the type of items in an array”

Comment: @Eduardo I stand corrected! I concur with your assessment above that the core problem is Swift's refusal to use the `IntegerType` protocol as a type due to its reference to `Self` (in `Equatable`). What I don't understand is _why_ referring to Self excludes its use as a type. Do you?

Comment: @ToddAgulnick: I am not sure why either. It seem to be an implementation restriction that may be overcome in a future version. We got no solution, but I enjoyed and learned from the opinion exchange. Thanks.

Comment: @Eduardo Likewise! Thanks for asking the question that started the discussion -- very educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved my problem was by defining the following protocol:

```
protocol IntegerArrayProtocol {
    init(rawData: NSData!, length: Int)

    func count() -> Int

    subscript(index:Int) -> Int { get }
}
```

This deals with all the operations I need to perform on the array:

1. Read it from raw memory
2. Count how many elements it has
3. Access its elements by index, always returning `Int`s, regardless of the underlying integer 
   type

Then, I created a parameterized class that implements the protocol:

```
final class IntegerArray<T: ConvertibleToInteger>: IntegerArrayProtocol {
    let arr: [T]

    init(rawData: NSData!, length: Int){
        //create array and allocate memory for all elements
        arr = Array<T>(count: length, repeatedValue: T.zero())

        // read it from the NSData source
        // ....
    }

    func count() -> Int{
        return arr.count
    }

    subscript(index:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return arr[index].asInt()
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter types `T` should be able to convert themselves to `Int`, and should have a `zero` value (used when I initialize the array). For that, I created the `ConvertibleToInteger` protocol, which is used above to restrict the possible `T`s:

```
protocol ConvertibleToInteger {
   class func zero() -> Self
   func asInt() -> Int
}
```

Then, I extended every type that I would like to create arrays of:

```
extension Int8: ConvertibleToInteger{
    static func zero() -> Int8{
        return 0
    }
    func asInt() -> Int{
        return Int(self)
    }
}

extension Int16: ConvertibleToInteger{
    static func zero() -> Int16{
        return 0
    }
    func asInt() -> Int{
        return Int(self)
    }
}

extension Int32: ConvertibleToInteger{
    static func zero() -> Int32{
        return 0
    }
    func asInt() -> Int{
        return Int(self)
    }
}

extension Int64: ConvertibleToInteger{
    static func zero() -> Int64{
        return 0
    }
    func asInt() -> Int{
        return Int(self)
    }
}
```

Finally, to read an array from NSData, I created the following function:

```
func readArray(rawData: NSData, length: Int): IntegerArrayProtocol? {
    qBytes = // read from NSData how many bytes each element is

    switch(qBytes){
      case 1:
          return IntegerArray<Int8>(rawData: rawData, length: length)
      case 2:
          return IntegerArray<Int16>(rawData: rawData, length: length)
      case 3 ... 4:
          return IntegerArray<Int32>(rawData: rawData, length: length)
      case 5 ... 8:
          return IntegerArray<Int64>(rawData: rawData, length: length)
      default:
          return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IntegerType` is a protocol, so the following should work:

```
class Test {
    func test(data:NSData) -> Array<T: IntegerType> {
      [1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it gives me a "'0' does not have the member 'Element'" error

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? It compiles for me using Version 6.1 (6A1030) (as reported by Xcode -> About Xcode)

Comment: Version 6.0.1 for iOS

Comment: Oh, I see now that you've edited the code since your original post -- The function signature I offered above works, but trying to return values from the function does indeed produce the error Rajeev Bhatia identified above.  The more I think about this, the less convinced I am that what you're attempting is possible: defining a function whose return value is a generic whose actual type is determined by the function's implementation (as opposed to the type of its input parameters). I can't think of an existing example. Can you?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why he wants to do this especially with Int since Apple explicitly advocates the use of the common Int type instead of the specific types

Comment: @RajeevBhatia I am writing a generic charting application which will need to work with very large arrays. If I use Int, it will allocate integers of 32 or 64 bits, which would be a waste of memory in the case my values are small. The range of values, and the number of arrays I will need are user-defined. I want to save as much memory as possible.

Comment: I see. How about just returning [Any] then since none of the generic answers are working. Let me post an answer about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enum` with associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_225) for that:

```
enum IntArray {
    case Int8([Swift.Int8])
    case Int16([Swift.Int16])
    case Int32([Swift.Int32])
    case Int64([Swift.Int64])
}


class Test {
    func test(data:NSData) -> IntArray {
        return IntArray.Int8([1, 2, 3]);
    }
}
```

on user side:

```
let obj = Test()
let array = obj.test(dat)

switch array {
case .Int8(let ary):
    // here, ary is [Int8]
    ...
case .Int16(let ary):
    // here, ary is [Int16]
    ...
case .Int32(let ary):
    // here, ary is [Int32]
    ...
case .Int64(let ary):
    // here, ary is [Int64]
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there isn't much I can do with the `IntArray` later. I need something that would let me operate with the array in a generic way.

Comment: Yeah I know. But, even if you can do like `Array<IntegerType>`, how can you extract the "value" of it? Sooner or later, you have to do the "Type Casting" and convert it to the final concrete type. Moreover, you have to do that for **every element** with `for in { switch { ... }}` loop, because the array could be like `[Int8, Int32, Int16, Int16, ...]`. I think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, this won't work if you are trying to determine the function's return type at runtime. Swift generics only work at compile time, so changing the return type based off of what's in an NSData won't work.

If you *can* determine the return type at compile time, then you can use a [generic function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_278) declaration like so:

```
func test<T: IntegerType>(data: NSData) -> Array<T> {
    return [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Note: If you don't specify the type explicitly in your function somehow, then you'll need to define the variable the value returned from the function is assigned to.  Like so:

```
var int8Array: Array<Int8> = test(NSData())
```

Comment: What I wanted to avoid is being explicit in my declaration, since the actual type will be determined at runtime, based on what I read from the NSData

Comment: @Eduardo that should work fine, my note was only if you didn't define the type in the function itself (by looking at the NSData in your case). I basically put it in there in case you just copied my answer to a playground and tried to run it.

Comment: @Eduardo actually, I take that back. If the Swift compiler doesn't know what the function will return at compile time, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the generic based solutions are working, why don't you try returning [Any] and just check the return type as follows:-

```
func test(data:NSData) -> [Any]
{
    var value1:Int8 = 1
    var value2:Int8 = 2
    return [value1,value2]
}

var x = test(NSData())
for xin in x
{
    var intxin = xin as? Int8
    if intxin != nil
    {
        println(intxin!)
    }
}
```