# When to use Type Constraints in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift

Swift documentation says that protocols are treated like any other types, but looking at some examples, I see that 'type constraint' construct is being used instead of protocol.

Let's take the Swift dictionary for an example:

```
struct Dictionary<Key: Hashable, Value>: CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible {
  // ...
  subscript (key: Key) -> Value?    
  // ...
}
```

Couldn't that have been written like this

```
struct Dictionary<Value>: CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible {
  // ...
  subscript (key: Hashable) -> Value?    
  // ...
}
```

?

I can see type constraint useful with *where* conditions for types with associated types, but I'm not sure about this specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to implement something like your second example, the compiler complains that `Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. This is because `Hashable` ultimately extends `Equatable`, which requires that both the left-hand and right-hand side of a equality statement be the *exact same type* as each other. In your second example, though, you're simply requiring that the dictionary key be `Hashable`, not that all keys be the same concrete type. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Right, right, "In your second example, though, you're simply requiring that the dictionary key be Hashable, not that all keys be the same concrete type.". Thanks!