# Set of protocols in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Having a Set of a specific interface in java is very useful:

```
HashSet<MyInterface> mySet;
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Swift?

I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
public protocol DialogDelegate : class, Hashable
{
    func myFunction()
}

public final class DialogManager: NSObject
{
    private var _dialogDelegates: Set<DialogDelegate>

    private override init()
    {
        _dialogDelegates = Set<DialogDelegate>()
        super.init();
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error:

> Protocol 'DialogDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: please explain what the error was.

Comment: I added the compiler error to the question.

Comment: why does your protocol use `Self` or associated types?

Comment: Because `DialogDelegate` inherits from `Hashable`, which in turn inherits from `Equatable`, which requires you implement `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is explained in: [What does "Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has)

To solve this you could use `DialogDelegate` as a generic type constraint:

```
public final class DialogManager<T: DialogDelegate>: NSObject {
    private var _dialogDelegates: Set<T>

    private override init()
    {
        _dialogDelegates = Set<T>()
        super.init();
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, this won't allow you allowed to mix the types of objects stored in `_dialogDelegates`; that may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: It's so silly that such simple task as creating set of protocols (commonly used when implementing the observer pattern) is impossible. You can't just inherit your protocol from `Hashable`. This solution (as well as all other possible ones) is clumsy and hacky.

Comment: I can say I share your anger @kelin.