# Check if "Any" is a "Sequence" in Swift

Tags: swift, sequence

Is there a way to use `Sequence` as a type through an if statement? I wanted to do the following

```
if value is Sequence {
    print("sequence")
}
```

But I get an error

> Protocol 'Sequence' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there some other way to check against Sequence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has)

Comment: @the4kman it's not because OP is trying to check protocol conformance