# How to Check the 'Equatable' protocol is implemented?

Tags: swift

```
if let equatableObj = newFirstItem as? Equatable {
    // do something
}
```

error message: Error:(140, 64) protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

How do i solve it?

Comment: [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24962353/5685969) This is just a swift constraint.

Comment: Be sure to use search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Swift+equatable A lot of similar questions answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associatedType requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348061/protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associa)

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very detailed post about this topic at [Swift by Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/questions/referencing-generic-protocols/)