# Understanding generics with a generic constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics

```
protocol Nameable: Equatable {
    var name: String { get set }
}

struct Person: Nameable {
    var name: String
}

struct Car: Nameable {
    var name: String
}
```

Now I can constrain a function to be able to print elements conforming to the `Nameable` protocol since they are of the same type?

```
func printNameable<T: Nameable>(_ list: [T]) {

}
```

But how I can create this list? I get a syntax Error.

```
var nameableList<T: Nameable>: [T] = []
```

Or if I try next I get *Protocol 'Nameable' can only be used as a generic constraint* ...

```
var nameables: [Nameable] = []
```

I am forced to specify a Nameable type like Person or Car to create this list?

Basically, in the end, **I want an array of a common protocol that can have a variety of different type objects that I can compare**, if they are of different type they are different, but if not, I want to compare them.

```
var nameables: [Nameable] = [Person(name: "John"), Car(name: "Ferrari")]

nameables.contains(Car(name: "Ferrari"))
```

(I guess both types, *Person* and *Car* should conform Equatable protocol).

Comment: This is because your `Namable` protocol extends `Equatable` protocol and `Equatable` has `func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` And a protocol that contains Self somewhere inside it cannot be used anywhere except in a type constraint. copied from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350283/219971) has a detailed explanation with a reference for deeper dive into understanding this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually pass `printNameable<T>(_:)` an array that contains both `Car` and `Person` objects, it can only contain one or the other. The generic type `T` isn't a runtime value, it's calculated at compile time, so if your code calls `printNameable(persons)` and `printNameable(cars)` you will actually have 2 different compiled functions (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

As @Sandeep Bhandari mentioned in their comment, since your protocol extends `Equatable`, which contains `Self`, your protocol can only be used as a generic constraint. If you want your protocol to be usable in the way that you want just remove `Equatable` and then change `printNameable(_:)` to

```
func printNameable(_ list: [Nameable]) {
}
```