# Protocol 'App' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, associated-types

a common example:

```
protocol Foo {
    
}

extension Foo {
    static func abc() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    
    static func abc() {
        // do something.

        (self as Foo.Type).abc() // it works well
    }
}
```

but if I add associatedtype (like SwiftUI.App) in protocol Foo, it report error:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Body = Scene
}

extension Foo {
    static func abc() {
        // ...
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    
    static func abc() {
        // do something.

        (self as Foo.Type).abc() // it reports error
    }
}
```

**Protocol 'Foo' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

how to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-the-error-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or-associated-type-requirements) out

Comment: @aheze it seems not working. (self as Protocol.Type) can work well on normal protocols without associatedtype. but I don't known how to express it.

Comment: How can you code what? What are you trying to do? You've already declared `@main` and adopted App. What else did you want to do?

Comment: @matt I try to make a custom `static func main()`, and then call `SwiftUI.App.main()` again like `super.main()`. it's just an experiment, Not limited

Comment: But there is no need to do that so why try? And what do you imagine `super` would mean? This is a struct, it has no inheritance.

Comment: @matt I have updated code 

Comment: Ok, I see. But what you're trying to do is still very artificial. Protocol extension for injection of method implementation is not a form of dynamic dispatch inheritance.

Comment: @matt It's just a little experiment. It looks like Foo::abc() in C++, I think we are able to call Foo.abc() in class Bar. Not dynamic dispatch but vtable

Comment: @JorrisGM: As far as I see in your code, you are trying hard code a function to a protocol which is not planed for that! you are calling a function from protocol that has nothing inside other than just a name!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926310/what-does-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has)