# Define dictionary without Types gives compiler error in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

I don't know the datatypes ahead of time, how can I add data to the empty dictionary without types. Looks like someone asked the same question here but no answer was accepted [How to create Dictionary that can hold anything in Key? or all the possible type it capable to hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119624/how-to-create-dictionary-that-can-hold-anything-in-key-or-all-the-possible-type)

Swift Compiler Error:

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression.

I get this error in `b["test"] = 23` this line.

```
var a = [String:Int]()
a["test"] = 23  # Works 


var b = [:]
b["test"] = 23 # Compiler Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `b` is of type `NSDictionary`, which is immutable. Therefore you get an error when trying to modify its contents.

You need to declare `b` as an `NSMutableDictionary` to make this work:

```
let dictionary: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
dictionary["key"] = "value" // No errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare you second dictionary as a Swift dictionary as well, but with `AnyObject` as the value type:

```
var b = [String:AnyObject]()
```

Then you can do:

```
b["test"] = 23
b["stuff"] = "hello world"
```

This value will be of type `AnyObject`, so you have to cast it back when you retrieve it:

```
let result = b["test"] as! Int
let sentence = b["stuff"] as! String
```

or

```
if let result = b["test"] as? Int {
    // use result (23)
}
if let sentence = b["stuff"] as? String {
    // use sentence ("hello world")
}
```

Comment: I have to define the key as String, When I try to define var d = [AnyObject:AnyObject](), I get an error 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Comment: @classyhacker you need to define it as NSObject:AnyObject you should always use Swift native dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
var b:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
b["test"] = 23
b[1] = "one"
b // ["test": 23, 1: "one"]
```