# How to add class name and line number to print() statement.

Tags: swift

How could you override `print()` to include the class and line number it was called from?

So `print("Hello world")` on line 17 of ViewController.swift would output:

`ViewController, 17: Hello world`

Comment: Use a [logging library](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack).

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495039/print-class-name-of-current-file-in-swift

Comment: I was hoping to override the functionality of print() without using a third party lib or using __FILE__ macro in every single print() statement.  I understand it may not be possible though.