# How do you access [NSObject class] in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do you do the following in Swift?

```
[SomeClass class]
```

The class method of NSObject is only available to Objective-C. How would you do the equivalent in Swift? I'm interfacing with an Objective-C 3rd party library.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

```
SomeClass.self
```

and if you have an instance:

```
someInstance.dynamicType
```