# Get Type from a class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possibile to retrive the data `Type` from a class in `Swift language` ?

This is an example :

```
class Test : NSObject
{
    let field1 : String
    let field2 : Int

    init(value1 : String, value2 : Int)
    {
        field1 = value1
        field2 = value2
    }
}

let test1 = Test(value1: "Hello", value2: 1)

//this code return the same string with class name (__lldb_expr_129.Test)
let classString = NSStringFromClass(test1.classForCoder) 
let className2 = reflect(test1).summary

//this code return the same ExistentialMetatype value and not the Tes or NSObject type
let classType = reflect(test1).valueType
let classType2 = test1.self.classForCoder

//this return Metatype and not the Test or NSObject type
let classType3 = test1.self.dynamicType
```

Is there a method to retrive the `Test` type and not the `ExistentialMetatype` or `Metatype`value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print the type or class of a variable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

1. `.self` on an object is pointless. `test1.self` is the same as `test1`
2. `test1.classForCoder` is the same as `test1.dynamicType` which is just `Test.self`. This is a *type* (a value of metatype type). Swift types currently do not have nice printable representations; but just because it doesn't print nice does not mean it's not what you want. Since in this case the type is a class, you can use `NSStringFromClass` or cast it to an object (giving you the Objective-C class object) and print that.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a method `objcet.getType()` like in C#

Comment: @PizzaRings He gave it to you, **you don't need a method**. Did you even read (2.). You wanted the *type of the class* that is `Test.self`.

Comment: @PizzaRings: Yes. `object.dynamicType` gives you the type. There is nothing wrong with it. It just doesn't look like anything when you print it.