# Is it possible to check types in Swift like in C#?

Tags: swift, swift2

Is it possible to do like this in Swift?

```
if (obj1.GetType() == obj2.GetType()) { /* do something */}
```

Comment: `if obj1 is obj2.dynamicType`?

Comment: @jtbandes Unfortunately it doesn't compile this code

Comment: you can check if objective1 is equal to object2 by if (obj1 === obj2) if that's what you are looking for .

Comment: @Sourav Sachdeva No, they are different instances of the same class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift                  or try this get type and see if the if condition can do that .

Comment: @Sourav Sachdeva Mirror struct did helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Mirror struct as mentioned in this question
[How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)
Here a few examples:

```
let var1 = "Test"
let var2 = "Hello World"
let var3 = UIView()
let var4 = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

let mirror1 = Mirror(reflecting: var1)
let mirror2 = Mirror(reflecting: var2)
let mirror3 = Mirror(reflecting: var3)
let mirror4 = Mirror(reflecting: var4)

print(mirror1.subjectType == mirror2.subjectType) // true
print(mirror2.subjectType == mirror3.subjectType) // false
print(mirror3.subjectType == mirror4.subjectType) // true
```