# Get the class type name of a UIView subclass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

**Description of problem**

If I type

```
print(someSubview)
```

I get something like this:

```
<UIButton: 0x7fb063e3d330; frame = (46 64; 464 41); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb063e3b010>>
```

What I would like is to just get name without all that other text:

```
UIButton
```

Of course, I could extract the substring programmatically, but I was wondering if there was something built in already. I only want this for debugging.

**These don't work**

```
print(someSubview.description)
print(someSubview.class)
print(someSubview.name)
```

Comment: `print(someSubview.dynamicType)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR, That was the question I was missing. Thanks. I am voting to close this as a duplicate.