# Swift - get class name

Tags: swift

I examined that question: [How do I print the type or class of a variable in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift)

But still i cant find answer, how to output class of object in Swift?

In Obj-C that was simple - `[myClass class];` but in swift i can't understand how to do that.

For example, consider following:

```
 let coordinates = (x: 3, y: 2, z: 5)
print(type(of: coordinates))
```

That output:"(Int, Int, Int)\n"

But i dont want to know what is inside, i want to know class name of coordinates! What is that? Tuple, an array or dictionary?

Can someone provide code snippet to explain that? Thanks!

Comment: `coordinates` doesn't have a class. It is a tuple and its type is `(Int, Int, Int)` as shown.

Comment: First of all, it's a struct not a class. Secondly, the type is a tuple of three `Int`s, what's wrong with the result?

Comment: @vadian why is that not a class? What if i want to define Array class like that or dictionary? Why swift decide for me whether i want create class or struct?

Comment: swift doesn't "decide"; if you declare a class it is a class. If it declare a struct it is a struct. Intrinsic types such as Int, tuples and collections such as arrays and dictionaries are value types.

Comment: @Paulw11 if i declare let X = @"123" isn't that a class String with value of 123 inside?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban String is a struct not a class

Comment: @LeoDabus isnt that equivalent of NSString class in Obj-C?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Similar but not the same. Can be converted to each other automatically but not the same.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban [myClass class] in Swift would be `class MyClass { ... }`

Comment: @LeoDabus let arr: Array = [1, 2, 3]
class.arr produce an error as well

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language, most of the time you don't need to tell it the type of your objects. `let arr = [1, 2, 3]` What is `class.arr` ?

Comment: @LeoDabus nothing, it product an error. Try it in playground please.

Comment: You need to specify the type of your array or let Swift infer the type which is preferred. `let arr: Array<Int> = [1, 2, 3]` or `let arr = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @LeoDabus good, i still cant get result from class.arr

Comment: `type(of: arr)` Why do you need that ?

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, but really, is there is separate struct called Array and NSArray class in Swift?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You don't need to use NSArray in Swift. You should use Array only.

Comment: And if arr is a property of your MyClass `class MyClass {
    
    let arr = [1, 2, 3]
}
type(of: MyClass().arr)`   or if it is a static property `class MyClass {
    
    static let arr = [1, 2, 3]
}
type(of: MyClass.arr)`

Comment: @LeoDabus why should i prefer to use struct over NSObject class?

Comment: The question is Why do you need to subclass NSObject? If you don't use a struct. You don't need to create initializers for a struct.

Comment: @LeoDabus because objects have usefull class methods that it inherit from super class? For example for NSArray - count, object at index, etc.?

Comment: You have it all with a struct. What do you mean ? The only case I see you would need to use a class would be subclassing or to make it persist making it NSCoding compliant. BTW Swift is a protocol oriented language.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You really should learn more about the benefits of value types and what you can do with a struct in Swift. Please read the [related section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82) in the Swift Programming Language manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple is a compound type and compound types don't have names. You can get the types of its elements as you said. So your code in your question is the right way to get the type of variable. For example, code below will print the type of dictionary.

```
let someDictionary = ["Alex": 31, "Paul": 39]
print(type(of: someDictionary))
```

Output : Dictionary < String, Int >

You can have more detailed information about types from [Swift Programming Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445).