# How to check for core data attribute type at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to check the type of attributes datatype at runtime in Swift. Like while inserting I want to check if the particular attribute in an entity accepts value of date type or string type. How this can be achieved in Swift.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006165/how-do-i-print-the-type-or-class-of-a-variable-in-swift.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Actually you are supposed to know the attributes and their types at runtime since the model is read-only.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use entity's attribute description which is of type **NSAttributeDescription** to find out the correct type of the property that is defined in model.

If say you have a subclass of **NSManagedObject**, Person. Then, you could use example from following code to check the type before inserting,

```
@objc(Person)
class Person: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged
  var name: String

  @NSManaged
  var age: NSNumber

  @NSManaged
  var dateOfBirth: Date
}

let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: context) as! Person

if let attribute = person.entity.attributesByName["name"],
                      attribute.attributeType == .stringAttributeType {

  // use your code here for custom logic
  print("name is string")
}

if let attribute = person.entity.attributesByName["age"], 
                      attribute.attributeType == .dateAttributeType {

  // use your code here for custom logic

  print("age is date")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `type(of:)`.E.g.,

```
let test: Int = 0
if type(of: test) == Int.self {
    print("found")
}
```

Comment: That's true for Swift in general but with Core Data it's better to use Core Data's reflection methods.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should know what your model is before you write your code. 
So introspecting on a readonly model seems a little silly.  I can't think of any reason why you would ever want to do this, but I'm sure you have a good reason that you aren't sharing.

You can look at a managedObject `entity` class method (on your subclass) which is a `NSEntityDescription`. Or you can get all the entity descriptions directly from your model object (`context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entites`) or if you know the entity's name you can use `context.persistentStoreCoordinator. managedObjectModel.entitiesByName["EntityName"]`.  The entity description will tell you all about the entities properties.  You can look through each of the attributes and get a `NSAttributeDescription` which will tell you the type for that attribute.