# Get class name of object as string in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection, typeof

Getting the classname of an object as `String` using:

```
object_getClassName(myViewController)
```

returns something like this:

```
_TtC5AppName22CalendarViewController
```

I am looking for the *pure* version: `"CalendarViewController"`. How do I get a *cleaned up* string of the class name instead?

I found some attempts of questions about this but not an actual answer. Is it not possible at all?

Comment: alternatively … what would an effective parser function for this look like?

Comment: In case you wish to check if an object is of a certain class see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37854871/1971013).

Answer (score 702):

String from an *instance*:

```
String(describing: self)
```

String from a *type*:

```
String(describing: YourType.self)
```

Example:

```
struct Foo {

    // Instance Level
    var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: Foo.self)
    }

    // Instance Level - Alternative Way
    var otherTypeName: String {
        let thisType = type(of: self)
        return String(describing: thisType)
    }

    // Type Level
    static var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}

Foo().typeName       // = "Foo"
Foo().otherTypeName  // = "Foo"
Foo.typeName         // = "Foo"
```

Tested with `class`, `struct` and `enum`.

Comment: Is this really the case?  According to the docs for String for this initializer "an unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard library" when it doesn't conform to Streamable, or CustomStringConvertible,  or CustomDebugStringConvertible.  So while it may be displaying the desired value now, will it continue to do so in the future?

Comment: Using this in Xcode 7.3.1 & Swift 2.2 produces the following, which is no ideal. ''let name = String(self) name String "<MyAppName.MyClassName: 0x########>"''

Comment: @CodeBender with a helper function [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34375827/3541063) you wouldn't care whether you have an instance or a type object.

Comment: In xcode 8/swift 3 I get <App_Name.ClassName: 0x79e14450>

Comment: In Swift 3, the proper answer is to call `String(describing: MyViewController.self)` as noted in a few answers below.

Comment: But it returns "MyViewController.TYPE"!

Comment: @orkenstein I just tried it in a playground. It returns `MyViewController`.

Comment: I prefer `type(of: self)` instead of `YourType.self` (Alternative Way in the example).

Comment: @MariánČerný From what I understand, `type(of:)` is evaluated dynamically at runtime whereas `Type.self` is not.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovič Yes, that would be true. But I don't like writing the class name explicitly (what If I rename the class `Foo` to `Foo2` but create a class `Foo` elsewhere, that might brake the code). In case of subclassing you need to use either `type(of:)` or `Type.self` depending what fits your need. Probably `type(of:)` is more appropriate for getting the class name.

Comment: "Alternative Way" should be the primary way.

Comment: For nested types, like `struct Foo { struct Bar {} }` and `struct OtherFoo { struct Bar{} }` we get the same name from `String(describing:Foo.Bar.self)` and `String(describing:OtherFoo.Bar.self)`. In this case, `String(reflecting:Foo.Bar.self)` is a better fit, because it will give us the fully qualified name of the type: `MyApp.Foo.Bar`.

Comment: Does it return valid name if there were some obfuscation?

Answer (score 231):

**UPDATED TO SWIFT 5**

*We can get pretty descriptions of type names **using the instance variable** through the `String` initializer and **create new objects of a certain class***

*Like, for example `print(String(describing: type(of: object)))`. Where `object` can be an **instance variable** like array, a dictionary, an `Int`, a `NSDate`, etc.*

Because `NSObject` is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, you could try to make an extension for `NSObject` to get the class name of every subclass of `NSObject`. Like this:

```
extension NSObject {
    var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Or you could make a static funcion whose parameter is of type `Any` (The protocol to which all types implicitly conform) and returns the class name as String. Like this:

```
class Utility{
    class func classNameAsString(_ obj: Any) -> String {
        //prints more readable results for dictionaries, arrays, Int, etc
        return String(describing: type(of: obj))
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
class ClassOne : UIViewController{ /* some code here */ }
class ClassTwo : ClassOne{ /* some code here */ }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get the class name as String
        let dictionary: [String: CGFloat] = [:]
        let array: [Int] = []
        let int = 9
        let numFloat: CGFloat = 3.0
        let numDouble: Double = 1.0
        let classOne = ClassOne()
        let classTwo: ClassTwo? = ClassTwo()
        let now = NSDate()
        let lbl = UILabel()

        print("dictionary: [String: CGFloat] = [:] -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(dictionary))")
        print("array: [Int] = [] -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(array))")
        print("int = 9 -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(int))")
        print("numFloat: CGFloat = 3.0 -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(numFloat))")
        print("numDouble: Double = 1.0 -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(numDouble))")
        print("classOne = ClassOne() -> \((ClassOne).self)") //we use the Extension
        if classTwo != nil {
            print("classTwo: ClassTwo? = ClassTwo() -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(classTwo!))") //now we can use a Forced-Value Expression and unwrap the value
        }
        print("now = Date() -> \(Utility.classNameAsString(now))")
        print("lbl = UILabel() -> \(String(describing: type(of: lbl)))") // we use the String initializer directly

    }
}
```

Also, once we can get the class name as String, **we can instantiate new objects of that class**:

```
// Instantiate a class from a String
print("\nInstantiate a class from a String")
let aClassName = classOne.theClassName
let aClassType = NSClassFromString(aClassName) as! NSObject.Type
let instance = aClassType.init() // we create a new object
print(String(cString: class_getName(type(of: instance))))
print(instance.self is ClassOne)
```

Maybe this helps someone out there!.

Comment: `classNameAsString` can be simplified to `className`, for that "name" implied its type. `theClassName` is simillar to facebook's story, which is named thefacebook originally.

Comment: "diccionary"...the Italian version of Swift's dictionary collection :]

Comment: This solution prepending projectname for each classTag, i.e. `ProjectTest.MyViewController`. How do I get rid of this project name? I want only class name.

Answer (score 164):

## Swift 5

Here is the extension to get the `typeName` as a variable (work with both value type or reference type).

```
protocol NameDescribable {
    var typeName: String { get }
    static var typeName: String { get }
}

extension NameDescribable {
    var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }

    static var typeName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
// Extend with class/struct/enum...
extension NSObject: NameDescribable {}
extension Array: NameDescribable {}
extension UIBarStyle: NameDescribable { }

print(UITabBarController().typeName)
print(UINavigationController.typeName)
print([Int]().typeName)
print(UIBarStyle.typeName)

// Out put:
UITabBarController
UINavigationController
Array<Int>
UIBarStyle
```

Comment: Any idea why i get MyAppName.MyClassName out of that? I'm only interest in MyClassName

Comment: @Andrew could you give more specific in your case? I'm using this extension in many projects and all of them response as intended.

Comment: Well if i call it from the class itself it return MyClassName, but if I wrap that in a method that returns the class name string and call it from another class it returns MyAppName.MyClassName. While searching around i saw that all classes are implicitly namespaced, so if you're to call it outside of your class you get MyAppName.MyClassName instead of MyClassName. Then you have to rely on string manipulation to get the class name.

Comment: very useful extension

Comment: @Andrew, not sure of current working, but I remember, String(describing: type(of: self)) used to return ModuleName.ClassName at one point. I had split based on . character and fetched the last object.

Answer (score 40):

Swift 5.2:

```
String(describing: type(of: self))
```

Answer (score 34):

I suggest such an approach (*very Swifty*):

```
// Swift 3
func typeName(_ some: Any) -> String {
    return (some is Any.Type) ? "\(some)" : "\(type(of: some))"
}

// Swift 2
func typeName(some: Any) -> String {
    return (some is Any.Type) ? "\(some)" : "\(some.dynamicType)"
}
```

It doesn't use neither introspection nor manual demangling (*no magic!*).

---

Here is a demo:

```
// Swift 3

import class Foundation.NSObject

func typeName(_ some: Any) -> String {
    return (some is Any.Type) ? "\(some)" : "\(type(of: some))"
}

class GenericClass<T> {
    var x: T? = nil
}

protocol Proto1 {
    func f(x: Int) -> Int
}


@objc(ObjCClass1)
class Class1: NSObject, Proto1 {
    func f(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x
    }
}

struct Struct1 {
    var x: Int
}

enum Enum1 {
    case X
}

print(typeName(GenericClass<Int>.self)) // GenericClass<Int>
print(typeName(GenericClass<Int>()))  // GenericClass<Int>

print(typeName(Proto1.self)) // Proto1

print(typeName(Class1.self))   // Class1
print(typeName(Class1())) // Class1
print(typeName(Class1().f)) // (Int) -> Int

print(typeName(Struct1.self)) // Struct1
print(typeName(Struct1(x: 1))) // Struct1
print(typeName(Enum1.self)) // Enum1
print(typeName(Enum1.X)) // Enum1
```

Comment: They changed it in Swift 3.0. Now you can get string from `type(of: self)`

Comment: Updated to Swift 3.

Comment: I think this is the best way to get type name: any instance of class, based on NSObject, enum, typealiase, functions, var properties, and any types, even constants. For types, you have to use .self. For example, typeName(Int.self), typeName(true.self). Nor you need to worry about project name as part(such as AppProj.[typename]) Great!

Answer (score 32):

Swift 3.0

`String(describing: MyViewController.self)`

Comment: Actually `type(of: )` is an overkill there, `String(describing: MyViewController.self)` will suffice

Comment: This creates a string such as <App_Name.ClassName: 0x79e14450> for me, which is not ideal

Comment: Isn't it `String.init(describing: MyViewController.self)`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, You can do that, but the `init` is unnecessary.

Comment: Totally get rid of the AppName prefix! Thanks

Comment: `type(of:)` is not overkill, it is much preferable. Because if you don't use it, the `debugDescription` property is called. Now if you want to override `debugDescription` and display the class name inside it, you get a StackOverflow.

Answer (score 29):

If you have type `Foo`, the following code will give you `"Foo"` in Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
let className = String(describing: Foo.self) // Gives you "Foo"
```

The problem with most of the answers on here are that they give you `"Foo.Type"` as the resulting string when you don't have any instance of the type, when what you really want is just `"Foo"`. The following gives you `"Foo.Type"`, as mentioned in a bunch of the other answers.

```
let className = String(describing: type(of: Foo.self)) // Gives you "Foo.Type"
```

The `type(of:)` part is unnecessary if you just want `"Foo"`.

Answer (score 25):

In **Swift 4.1** and now **Swift 4.2** :

```
import Foundation

class SomeClass {
    class InnerClass {
        let foo: Int

        init(foo: Int) {
            self.foo = foo
        }
    }

    let foo: Int

    init(foo: Int) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

class AnotherClass : NSObject {
    let foo: Int

    init(foo: Int) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init()
    }
}

struct SomeStruct {
    let bar: Int

    init(bar: Int) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

let c = SomeClass(foo: 42)
let s = SomeStruct(bar: 1337)
let i = SomeClass.InnerClass(foo: 2018)
let a = AnotherClass(foo: 1<<8)
```

If you don't have an instance around:

```
String(describing: SomeClass.self) // Result: SomeClass
String(describing: SomeStruct.self) // Result: SomeStruct
String(describing: SomeClass.InnerClass.self) // Result: InnerClass
String(describing: AnotherClass.self) // Result: AnotherClass
```

If you do have an instance around:

```
String(describing: type(of: c)) // Result: SomeClass
String(describing: type(of: s)) // Result: SomeStruct
String(describing: type(of: i)) // Result: InnerClass
String(describing: type(of: a)) // Result: AnotherClass
```

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 5.1**

You can get class, struct, enum, protocol and NSObject names though `Self.self`.

```swift
print("\(Self.self)")
```

Comment: Note that this may prepend the module name (differently to `String(describing: type(of: self))`)

Comment: Yes, it looks so concise but also prepends the module name and I'd say it is a wrong answer to the question...

Comment: This is not working on release build config, it will return Self as a String. Any good explanation why is this happening?

Answer (score 20):

To get name of a Swift class from an object, e.g. for var object: SomeClass(), use

```
String(describing: type(of: object))
```

To get name of a Swift class from a class type, e.g. SomeClass, use:

```
String(describing: SomeClass.self)
```

Output:

> "SomeClass"

Answer (score 18):

You can try this way:

```
self.classForCoder.description()
```

Comment: This works great as it includes the full "namespace" (the appropriate target membership prefix) as well.

Comment: BTW, I also found using "String(self)" where self is an instance of MyViewController works too ... it provides the same information ... Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 16):

Swift 5:

Way 1:

```swift
print("Class: \(String(describing: self)), Function: \(#function), line: \(#line)")
```

Output:

```swift
Class: <Test.ViewController: 0x7ffaabc0a3d0>, Function: viewDidLoad(), line: 15
```

Way 2:

```swift
print("Class: \(String(describing: type(of: self))), Function: \(#function), line: \(#line)")
```

Output:

```swift
Class: ViewController, Function: viewDidLoad(), line: 16
```

Answer (score 15):

To get the type name as a string in **Swift 4** (I haven't checked the earlier versions), just use string interpolation:

```
"\(type(of: myViewController))"
```

You can use `.self` on a type itself, and the `type(of:_)` function on an instance:

```
// Both constants will have "UIViewController" as their value
let stringFromType = "\(UIViewController.self)"
let stringFromInstance = "\(type(of: UIViewController()))"
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the Swift standard library function called `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName` like this:

```
let name = _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(myViewController)
```

Comment: @NeilJaff what do you mean by "just an optional string"? It returns a string and it's not optional.

Comment: This approach doesn't return the names of classes in private APIs FYI. It will return the name of the first public base class name.

Comment: I get the message: Use of unresolved identifier '_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName'

Answer (score 10):

One can also use mirrors:

```
let vc = UIViewController()

String(Mirror(reflecting: vc).subjectType)
```

NB: This method can also be used for Structs and Enums. There is a displayStyle that gives an indication of what type of the structure:

```
Mirror(reflecting: vc).displayStyle
```

The return is an enum so you can:

```
Mirror(reflecting: vc).displayStyle == .Class
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what worked for me. The only thing (at least on iOS 9) is that the subjectType was ending in ".Type", so I had to remove that part from the string.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3.0:**
You can create an extension like this one.. It gives back the class name without the project name

```
extension NSObject {
    var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self as! AnyClass).components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? ""
    }

    public class var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: When I attempt to use this I get the error: Could not cast value of type 'ProjectName.MyViewController' (0x1020409e8) to 'Swift.AnyObject.Type' (0x7fb96fc0dec0).

Answer (score 9):

You can extend `NSObjectProtocol` in Swift 4 like this :

```
import Foundation

extension NSObjectProtocol {

    var className: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

This will make calculated variable `className` available to ALL classes. Using this inside a `print()` in `CalendarViewController` will print `"CalendarViewController"` in console.

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking for this answer off and on for a while.  I use GKStateMachine and like to observe state changes and wanted an easy way to see just the class name.  I'm not sure if it's just iOS 10 or Swift 2.3, but in that environment, the following does exactly what I want:

```
let state:GKState?
print("Class Name: \(String(state.classForCoder)")

// Output:    
// Class Name: GKState
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the name of the class doing something like:

```
class Person {}
String(describing: Person.self)
```

Answer (score 5):

To get class name as String declare your class as following

```
@objc(YourClassName) class YourClassName{}
```

And get class name using following syntax

```
NSStringFromClass(YourClassName)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `reflect().summary` on Class self or instance dynamicType.  Unwrap optionals before getting dynamicType otherwise the dynamicType is the Optional wrapper.

```
class SampleClass { class InnerClass{} }
let sampleClassName = reflect(SampleClass.self).summary;
let instance = SampleClass();
let instanceClassName = reflect(instance.dynamicType).summary;
let innerInstance = SampleClass.InnerClass();
let InnerInstanceClassName = reflect(innerInstance.dynamicType).summary.pathExtension;
let tupleArray = [(Int,[String:Int])]();
let tupleArrayTypeName = reflect(tupleArray.dynamicType).summary;
```

The summary is a class path with generic types described.  To get a simple class name from the summary try this method.

```
func simpleClassName( complexClassName:String ) -> String {
    var result = complexClassName;
    var range = result.rangeOfString( "<" );
    if ( nil != range ) { result = result.substringToIndex( range!.startIndex ); }
    range = result.rangeOfString( "." );
    if ( nil != range ) { result = result.pathExtension; }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The above solutions didn't work for me. The produced mostly the issues mention in several comments:

> MyAppName.ClassName

or

> MyFrameWorkName.ClassName

This solutions worked on XCode 9, Swift 3.0:

I named it `classNameCleaned` so it is easier to access and doesn't conflict with future `className()` changes:

```
extension NSObject {

static var classNameCleaned : String {

    let className = self.className()
    if className.contains(".") {
        let namesArray = className.components(separatedBy: ".")
        return namesArray.last ?? className
    } else {
        return self.className()
    }

}
```

}

Usage:

```
NSViewController.classNameCleaned
MyCustomClass.classNameCleaned
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5

```
 NSStringFromClass(CustomClass.self)
```

Answer (score 4):

This kind of example for class var. Don't include the name of bundle.

```
extension NSObject {
    class var className: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.0 (macOS 10.10 and later), you can get it from className

```
self.className.components(separatedBy: ".").last!
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no built-in className property in Swift classes. Did you subclass from something?

Comment: @shim className is declared in Foundation but It seems that it's only available on macOS 10.10 and later. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Why would they not include it in iOS? Also note it's an instance method on `NSObject`  https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1411337-classname

Answer (score 3):

I tried `type(of:...)` in Playground with Swift 3. This is my result.[image]
This is the code format version.

```
print(String(describing: type(of: UIButton.self)))
print(String(describing: type(of: UIButton())))
UIButton.Type
UIButton
```

Comment: It's wasteful to instantiate an instance just to determine the class name.

Comment: @sethfri I use this to determine the dynamic type.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to create an instance just to get the class's type information

Answer (score 3):

This solution will work for all the classes

Swift 5 solution:

```
extension NSObject {
  var className: String {
    return String(describing: type(of: self))
  }

  class var className: String {
    return String(describing: self)
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableVIewCell {
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
  let cellClassName = TextFieldCell.className
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.1 :-**

You can also use generic function for get class name of object as string

```
struct GenericFunctions {
 static func className<T>(_ name: T) -> String {
        return "\(name)"
    }

}
```

Call this function by using following:-

```
let name = GenericFunctions.className(ViewController.self)
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the mangled name, you can dictate your own name:

```
@objc(CalendarViewController) class CalendarViewController : UIViewController {
    // ...
}
```

However, it would be better in the long run to learn to parse the mangled name. The format is standard and meaningful and won't change.

Comment: No it's not, for my class it returns (ExistentialMetatype) - relying on undocumented runtime behavior is always dangerous, especially for swift since it's still in a relatively early stage.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the other solutions will give a non useful name depending on what object you are trying to look at. In that case you can get the class name as a string using the following.

```
String(cString: object_getClassName(Any!))
```

⌘ click the function in xcode to see some related methods that are fairly useful. or check here https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/objective_c_functions

Answer (score 0):

I use it in Swift 2.2

```
guard let currentController = UIApplication.topViewController() else { return }
currentController.classForCoder.description().componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case String(describing: self) returned something like:

> < My_project.ExampleViewController: 0x10b2bb2b0>

But I'd like to have something like `getSimpleName` on Android.

So I've created a little extension:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func getSimpleClassName() -> String {
        let describing = String(describing: self)
        if let dotIndex = describing.index(of: "."), let commaIndex = describing.index(of: ":") {
            let afterDotIndex = describing.index(after: dotIndex)
            if(afterDotIndex < commaIndex) {
                return String(describing[afterDotIndex ..< commaIndex])
            }
        }
        return describing
    }

}
```

And now it returns:

> ExampleViewController

Extending NSObject instead of UIViewController should also work. Function above is also fail-safe :)

Comment: Thats because your passing an instance of the class name instead of a class
so in the above example you should pass ExampleViewController.self