# Swift, a function defined in super class that returns the class name of subclass when called from a subclass object

Tags: swift, core-data

In Objective-C I can do this:

```
@interface MyManagedObjectSuperClass : NSManagedObject 
+(NSString*)entityName;
@end

@implementation
+(NSString*)entityName
{
    return NSStringFromClass([self class])
}
@end
```

With this base class, all my other `NSManagedObjects` can inherit from MyManagedObjectSuperClass. I can get the entity name by calling `+entityName`, since there is `polymorphism`, in subclasses, `NSStringFromClass([self class])` returns the class name of subclass.

So my question is, can I do this in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get class name of object as string in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494784/get-class-name-of-object-as-string-in-swift)

Comment: @bjtitus it's not a duplicate, I need to get it from a type instead of an instance, and I need polymorphism

Comment: `NSStringFromClass()` works in Swift as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27112385/1187415 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

In a *class method* of an `NSObject` subclass, both

```
toString(self)
NSStringFromClass(self)
```

return a string containing the class name (including product module name)
of the actual subclass on which the method is called.

See [How can I create instances of managed object subclasses in a NSManagedObject Swift extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109268/how-can-i-create-instances-of-managed-object-subclasses-in-a-nsmanagedobject-ext)
for an example how to extract the Core Data entity name from the full
class name.

Answer (score 1):

Is this straightforward approach what you need?

```
class Base {

    class func typeName() -> String {
        return "\(self)"
    }

}

class X: Base {}

print(Base.typeName()) // Base
print(X.typeName()) // X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamicType` to obtain the class name (inclusive of the module name), and string interpolation to convert it to a string:

```
class Class1 {
    var entityName: String {
        return "\(self.dynamicType)"
    }
}
```

The most obvious difference is that it's an instance and not a static property/method - that's probably a limitation in your case, as I presume you want to obtain the name from the type and not an instance of it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I need to get the name from a type instead of an instance