# UIWebView and Swift: Detect when a video starts playing

Tags: ios, swift2, subclassing, nsnotification

In Objective-C, I subscribed to the `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` to know if some view gets above my current view controller, using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoStartedPlaying:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

So far, so good. Then, in the notification, I could check if the object is **not** of certain classes (like `_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow` -alert views- or `UITextEffectsWindow` -native sharing view-). In Objective-C, I did it this way:

```
- (void)videoStartedPlaying:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (
        <radio_is_playing>
        &&
        ! [notification.object isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow")] // Alert view
        &&
        ! [notification.object isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITextEffectsWindow") ] // Share
        )
    {
        // Video, stop the radio stream
    }
}
```

This allowed me to stop playing sounds (in this case, an HTTP radio streaming) when starting a video from a `UIWebView` (which is used to present news). I've tried to do the same thing in Swift, so I subscribed to the notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "videoStartedPlaying:", name: UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification, object: nil)
```

And now, when receiving the notification...

```
func videoStartedPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
    if <radio_is_playing> && !notification.object? is _UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow && !notification.object? is UITextEffectsWindow {
        // Stop the radio stream
    }
}
```

Xcode says `Use of undeclared type '_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow'`. The same thing happens with `UITextEffectsWindow`.

I assume that I have to import **something** to detect those classes, but what should I import?

Is there any other way to do it without bridging Objective-C? How could I access that class?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Has nobody get into this?

Comment: I just check if the notification.objevt is UIWindow, do the pause thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could compare the class name instead the class itself, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494784/get-class-name-of-object-as-string-in-swift) to get the class name.

Comment: It's working with the first option. I saw that answer before and I don't know why it didn't work at that time. Thanks a lot. EDIT: For reference, if anyone else wants to do something similar, when presenting the share action (after pressing, for example, "Messages"), now a new event `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` appears too.