# How to print the object name (not class) in Swift?

Tags: swift

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26649394/3003927), I know that I can get the name of the class type using

```
NSStringFromClass(YourClassName)
```

But I actually also need the name of the *current object instance*. So if I have code like this:

```
let loginForm = LoginFormViewController();
```

I want to actually get the `loginForm` in string, within the implementation of `LoginFormViewController`.

How can I do that?

Comment: No you can't – local variable names get stripped away upon compilation. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Hamish For debugging purposes. I print a lot of information in debugging console, and having the name of the variable will help me to locate through tons of words. Well, I guess I'm out of luck then. Thanks!